# Google Maps API v.3 multiple markers infowindows

Tags: google-maps-api-3, marker, infowindow

I've looked through a lot of the similar questions on here, but have not found anything that will answer my question. I am new to JS and GoogleMaps API v3, and have successfully followed their tutorials to get this far. However, I'd like to have an infowindow with custom content appear based on which marker is clicked, and I cannot figure out how to do this. I'd also like to have this be possible with around 100 markers, so I'd like to know the best way to do this as well without things getting too messy. To be clear, there are 3 types of icons, but there will eventually be many markers associated with each icon, so I will need content linked to each "feature". Hopefully I've got a good start here and am not way off base. I've included the code for the page. Thank you so much in advance for any help anyone can provide.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 800px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color:#CCC;
      }
       #legend {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 3px solid #000;
      }
      #legend img {
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.137551,-0.703125),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        map.set('styles', [
        {
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
            { color: '#888888' },
            { weight: 1.0 }
            ]
        }, {
            featureType: 'landscape',
            elementType: 'geometry.fill',
            stylers: [
            { hue: '#008f11' },
            { gamma: 1.0 },
            { saturation: 0 },
            { lightness: -10 }
            ]       
        }, {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'geometry.fill',
            stylers: [
            { hue: '#054d8fd' },
            { gamma: 1.0 },
            { saturation: 0 },
            { lightness: -10 }
            ]       
        }, {
            featureType: 'poi',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { visibility: 'off' }
            ]
            }
        ]);
        var iconBase = 'http://i1318.photobucket.com/albums/t658/greatergoodorg/';
        var icons = {
            people: {
                name: 'People',
                icon: iconBase + 'people_zps26d13009.png',
                shadow: iconBase + 'shadow-people_zps4b39eced.png'
            },
            pets: {
                name: 'Pets',
                icon: iconBase + 'pets_zps15f549f2.png',
                shadow: iconBase + 'shadow-pets_zps361068aa.png'
            },
            planet: {
                name: 'Planet',
                icon: iconBase + 'planet_zps2a8572ce.png',
                shadow: iconBase + 'shadow-planet_zps9912e26b.png',
            }
        };
        var data = ["This is the first one", "This is the second one", "This is the third one"];
        function addMarker(feature) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: feature.position,
                icon: icons[feature.type].icon,  
                shadow: {
                    url: icons[feature.type].shadow,
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 32)
                },
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                map: map
            });
            /*...
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                 infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
            ...*/
        /*...
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        map.setZoom(8);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });
        ...*/
        }
        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.137551,-0.703125),
            type: 'planet'
          },
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.234234,-0.232233),
            type: 'pets'
          },
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.234234,-0.032233),
            type: 'people'
          }
          ];
        for (var i = 0, feature; feature = features[i]; i++) {
          addMarker(feature);
          } 
        var legend = document.getElementById('legend');
        for (var key in icons) {
          var type = icons[key];
          var name = type.name;
          var icon = type.icon;
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + icon + '"> ' + name;
          legend.appendChild(div);
        }
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM].push(
        document.getElementById('legend'));
    }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>        
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="legend"><strong>Project Types</strong></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you setting the content of the infowindow?  Where do you define the infowindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open an infowindow and display the "type" string in it

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function addMarker(feature) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,  
        shadow: {
           url: icons[feature.type].shadow,
           anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 32)
        },
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
     infowindow.setContent(feature.type);
         infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's great! What I'm looking for is a way to display some other type of custom content. So if I wanted the "pet" icon to say - "I like cats", and the people one to say - "I like people", etc. However, this should not be tied to feature.type, but to the location of the pin. And I'm hoping to duplicate this for about 100 markers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that documentation, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: thank you for helping out. I have things working the way I want them to. I'm now storing what I want to show in the info window in a string called "data" - I suspect there may be a better way to display HTML, could you let me know if this looks good to you?

var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.137551,-0.703125),
            type: 'planet',
   data: '<a href="http://www.google.com">check it out</a> one <br> <img       src="https://www01.wellsfargomedia.com/assets/images/global/wf-logo.gif">'
          }
    ];